# Context type error http post visual basic

Tags: vb.net, httpwebrequest, httprequest

I have been trying to send an HTTP post to a web service and got this message:

> "The 'Content-Type' header must be modified using the appropiat
>   property or method, Parameter nama:name"

This happens when i try to update a customer with this JSON fotmat :

```
{"display_name":"john smith","email":"johnsmith@something","company_name":"enterprise"}
```

This is a part of the code i have been using to connect to the API:

```
       Dim sUrl As String = "https://subscriptions.zoho.com/api/v1/customers"
       Dim wHeader As WebHeaderCollection = New WebHeaderCollection()
       Dim wRequest As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(sUrl), HttpWebRequest)
       wHeader.Clear()


        wHeader.Add("Authorization: Zoho-authtoken 7ca5747efb3be868e155e707e679f9f5")
        wHeader.Add("X-com-zoho-subscriptions-organizationid: 397080968")
        wHeader.Add("Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8")
        wRequest.Accept = "application/json"
        MsgBox(wHeader.ToString)
        wRequest.Headers = wHeader
        wRequest.Method = "POST"
        Dim postData As String = sw.ToString
        MsgBox(postData)
        Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)
        wRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
        Dim dataStream As Stream = wRequest.GetRequestStream()
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
        dataStream.Close()
        Dim response As WebResponse = wRequest.GetResponse()
        Console.WriteLine(CType(response, HttpWebResponse).StatusDescription)
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream()
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
        Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
        Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer)
        LblResponse.Text = sResponse
        Console.WriteLine(sResponse)
        reader.Close()
        dataStream.Close()
        response.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        If ex.InnerException IsNot Nothing Then
            LblResponse.Text = ex.Message + " >> " + ex.InnerException.ToString()

        Else
            LblResponse.Text = ex.Message
        End If

    End Try
```

any ideas ?

Comment: Maybe you have to add parameter of "name"?

Comment: the only way I ever get these things right is to debug the request with Fiddler.

Comment: @Alfonso : Did you get the solutions? If not, i'll help.